# xforms:select1 using xxforms:tree appearance rendering multiple different instances, how to control depth of rendering/branches?

Tags: orbeon

I am rendering three different instances (itemsets) using xforms:select1 with xxforms:tree appearance.  The first instance (itemset) renders fine,the second instance (itemset) renders at a depth level where the last item from the first instance (itemset) was rendered (e.g., at depth level 2 instead of at top level) and so on.

How do I control at what level an itemset gets rendered?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about **which** items are shown in the tree, then the answer is: all the items pointed to by your `<xforms:itemset>`. If you wish to limit the depth level, then you need to change the `nodeset` expression accordingly.